# Method is updating the DataSet, but not the underlying database, why?

Tags: c#, ado.net, sql-update, dataset

I have a project of type Windows Forms i Visual Studio 2010 Express.

I have created a service based local database and am able to show its data in textboxes on my Form and skipping through each of the records with buttons “Next” and “Previous”. So I have a connection to the database.

However, when I want to update the database with a new record with data from the textboxes when I click the Button “SAVE”, the data are only stored in the dataset and showed in the textboxes when I reach their position with the buttons, but not stored in the database. The next time I open the application, the new “stored” record is therefore gone.

Any idea where the error is in my code? Thanks a lot.

Here is the code for my save button in the file Form1.cs:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataRow row = ds.Tables[0].NewRow();
    row[1] = textBox1.Text;
    row[2] = textBox2.Text;
    row[3] = textBox3.Text;
    row[4] = textBox4.Text;

    ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(row);

    try
    {
        objConnect.UpdateDatabase(ds);

        MaxRows += 1;
        inc = MaxRows - 1;

        MessageBox.Show("Database updated");
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message);              
    }

    btnCancel.Enabled = false;
    btnSave.Enabled = false;
    btnAddNew.Enabled = true;
}
```

And here is the code for my class DatabaseConnection:

```
class DatabaseConnection
{
    private string sql_string;
    private string strCon;        
    private SqlDataAdapter da_1;

    public string Sql { set { sql_string = value; } }

    public string connection_string { set { strCon = value; } }

    public DataSet GetConnection { get { return MyDataSet(); } }

    private DataSet MyDataSet() 
    { 
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strCon);
        con.Open();
        da_1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql_string, con);
        DataSet dat_set = new System.Data.DataSet();
        da_1.Fill(dat_set, "Table_Data_1");
        con.Close();
        return dat_set;        
    }

    public void UpdateDatabase(System.Data.DataSet ds)
    {
        SqlCommandBuilder cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da_1);
        cb.DataAdapter.Update(ds.Tables[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: If the database is one that's created as part of your project; and it is copied to the bin folder each time you run, then what would happen is the version in the bin folder gets updated; but then when you run again, the source version is copied to the bin folder again, over-writing what is there previously ie losing your changes. Can you confirm the path to your database ?

Comment: Hello. Yes, here it is: The database (“Database1”) is placed in the same folder as the Program.cs file and the Form1.cs file. This is one level above the bin folder. In the Debug folder stored in the bin folder there is a copy of the Database1 and also of Database1_log.

Comment: Ok.. you can test to see if your database writes are working by running the program; doing the changes; then quit. Now go into the bin folder and run your program directly by the exe file; have your changes taken effect ? Or you can test by opening a new database connection to the db in the bin directory and looking at the data there. If this is all good; then the issue is definately copying the database each time. To change, put the database in a separate folder and alter the connection string to point there instead.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I'll try that then.